# How do I do a request.write(body) without the body?

Tags: node.js, https, request, httprequest

I am using the code as shown below. However I want to include the body in the query string (which I can do fine) - however, I am unsure how to restructure the`https.request` so as to remove `request.write(body)` - simply using `request.write()` does not work as it requires a string.

Can someone help?

Thanks

```
var body = JSON.stringify( json.text );
const params = {
    'q': body,
};

var requestUrl = url.parse( URL + queryStringify(params) );
const requestOptions = {
    hostname: requestUrl.hostname,
    path: requestUrl.path,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
};

var request = https.request(requestOptions, function(res) {
var data = "";
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
//do stuff
});
    res.on('end', function () {
//do stuff
    });        
});
request.write(body);
request.end();
```

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you can set your params in `path` field, with [querystring](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) like this :

**Set your query string params into requestOptions**

```
const querystring = require('querystring');
requestOptions.path = `/your/Path?${querystring.stringify({firstName: 'John', lastName: 'doe'})}`;
// Result is '/your/Path?firstName=John&lastName=doe'
```

**Then, do your request**

```
var request = https.request(requestOptions, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        // Do stuff
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        // Do stuff
    });
});
request.on('error', function (err) {
    // Throw err
});
request.end();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response. I have added more code to show how I am adding query parameters - However the response seems to act as if nothing is sent in `q`. But if I type the full url (as retrieved from context.log - then it does return correct data)

Comment: It seems to think I send `q=null` - do I need to encode/alter the `body` somehow?

Comment: Can you console.log "body" just after your JSON.stringify ?

Comment: Yes - it comes out correct, you URL works as well with the query string etc as when I type it into Chrome it returns the data. However when using https.request, it doesn't seem to send a valid `q` or it still expects a body to be sent and it thus null - I am not sure why it is happening